# How to style secondary nav menu without affecting main nav?

Tags: css, wordpress, genesis

I added a secondary navigation menu (above the header) and it's dropdown menus look the same as my main navigation dropdowns. I'm wanting to style them separately without messing up my main nav. Any ideas how I could do this? I'm also trying to right align it. [This is my test site](http://gleefulthings.com/WPtestblog/2015/12/16/tree-hugger-mittens-pattern/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've given the secondary menu a class of `nav-secondary`. As a result, you can use this to alter the styles of anything in that menu via `.nav-secondary .another-selector`. For example:

```
.nav-secondary .sub-menu {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could target the subnav for that list item using:

```
li#menu-item-72 ul.sub-menu { new styles here }
```

Comment: Won't that only affect one item? I need to style the whole drop down as well.